# Unable to format SD card

Tags: partitioning, formatting, sd-card

I am trying to format my SD card, but everything so far has failed. I tried using `diskpart`, when deleting a partition using `delete partition #` it simply doesn't delete the partition, always showing both partitions.

I've tried using `gparted`, whereas the same problem happened. I deleted both partitions and pressed apply to save the changes, where both partitions showed back up once again.

Another program I tried is `Minitool Partition Wizard`, once again when I try to delete both partitions and apply the changes, they both re-appear.

The SD card is a Samsung EVO 16GB.

I am unsure on how to continue, anyone has any ideas?

Comment: Your SD card is may be dead, but there have also be a LOT of similar questions in the past: Have you read these: https://superuser.com/questions/1151841/i-cannot-format-my-micro-sd-card https://superuser.com/search?q=cannot+format+sd+card

Comment: You talk about formatting in your title then talk about partitioning in your question text... which is it?

Comment: Was it by default that the SD card has partition? If not then how did you create the partitions? Minitool Partition Wizard? I do not have a solution but my first thought was that the partition table is not getting deleted and hence it shows up the partitions every time.